# Multiple read from a txt file in bash (threading)

Tags: bash, curl, xargs, gnu-parallel

Here is a simple bash script for HTTP status code

```
 while read url
    do
        urlstatus=$(curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out  '%{http_code}' "${url}" --max-time 5 )
        echo "$url  $urlstatus" >> urlstatus.txt
    done < $1
```

I am reading URL from text file but it processes only one at a time, taking too much time, GNU parallel and `xargs`  also process one line at time (tested)

How to process simultaneous  URL for processing to improve timing? In other words threading  of URL file rather than bash commands (which GNU parallel and `xargs` do)

```
Input file is txt file and lines are separated  as
ABC.Com
Bcd.Com
Any.Google.Com
Something  like this
```

.

Comment: reading a line from the file is not taking the time. `cURL` is taking the time... See if running `curl` as a background process an option for you.

Comment: this is something i do often with `parallel`. if you show what you tried with `parallel` and `xargs`, maybe someone will find a minor, fixable problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> GNU parallel and xargs also process one line at time (tested)

Can you give an example of this? If you use `-j` then you should be able to run much more than one process at a time.

I would write it like this:

```
doit() {
    url="$1"
    urlstatus=$(curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out  '%{http_code}' "${url}" --max-time 5 )
    echo "$url  $urlstatus"
}
export -f doit
cat "$1" | parallel -j0 -k doit >> urlstatus.txt
```

Based on the input:

```
Input file is txt file and lines are separated  as
ABC.Com
Bcd.Com
Any.Google.Com
Something  like this
www.google.com
pi.dk
```

I get the output:

```
Input file is txt file and lines are separated  as  000
ABC.Com  301
Bcd.Com  301
Any.Google.Com  000
Something  like this  000
www.google.com  302
pi.dk  200
```

Which looks about right:

```
000 if domain does not exist
301/302 for redirection
200 for success
```

Comment: I am doing like cat any.txt | parallel  - j100 /bash. Sh filelist.txt

Comment: and  n1 is also tested

Comment: Ahh, that explains it. Consider walking through `man parallel_tutorial`. It will explain this and give you a better understanding of why it works like it does.

Comment: actually your code (i tested ) is quite fast but instead of actual status code it gives 000 as status code ,, any suggestions

Comment: You will need to give us a few lines of example from the inputfile to test and debug with. Update your question with that. (And consider leaving -j at 0).

Comment: I will try with - j0,  then update with another comment

Comment: providing with j0 also gives the same results as status code 000 , any other options

Answer (score 1):

you mentioned you didn't have good luck with GNU `parallel`. maybe try this way?

```
format='curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out "%{http_code}" "%s"; echo "%s"\n'

awk -v fs="$format" '{printf fs, $0, $0}' url-list.txt | parallel
```

want e.g. 128 simultaneous processes?

```
awk -v fs="$format" '{printf fs, $0, $0}' url-list.txt | parallel -P128
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    #!/bin/bash
while read LINE; do
  curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{http_code}' "$LINE" & echo
  echo " $LINE"
done < url-list.txt
```

You are reading line by line a file and passing the line to curl which is getting the stuff  and THEN when CURL has finished it will read the new line. So to avoid that you need to do add **& echo**

a nasty example :

```
file="/tmp/url-list.txt"
echo "hello 1" >>$file 
echo "hello 2" >>$file
echo "hello3" >>$file 
while read line ;do 
  sleep 3 && echo "i run after sleep 3 - $line"  & echo "i runn as the same time of sleep 3"
done< "$file"
```